# Angular 2 Syntax Error Uncaught token during refreshing page with inner directory on URL - Nodejs Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I am trying to open a page with inner directory such as ***localhost:1000/register/100*** using Angular 2. On button click to navigate to that URL works perfectly but going to that page manually by typing on the URL or refreshing that page will give syntax error uncaught token

[image: directory]
[image: error]

The URL of the files on that error are stated

**localhost:1000/register/node_modules/....**

**localhost:1000/register/systemjs.config,js/....**

it seems that it is not getting node_modules and systemjs path correctly.
From my research, there are many who are encountering the same problem but without a solution. Is there a way to go around this?

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    path = require('path'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    port = process.env.PORT || 1000;

db = require('./config/db');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(db.url);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'test',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
require('./config/passport')(passport);
require('./routes/main')(app, passport);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));

app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('/view/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

I've also added

```
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
```

index.html

```
<head>
    <title>MET2U</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
    System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <base href="/">
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

but nothing seems to be working.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you change `app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));` with `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/view/index.html'));` and try?

Comment: @echonax did as you said, still same error

Comment: Can you share your index.html

Comment: @echonax added index.html. Actually serving localhost:1000 works, but going into an inner directory such as localhost:1000/register/100 doesn't work. It seems that it is not getting node_modules path correctly in the inner directory